# What does a value of -1.000 mean in MS COCO Metrics for Object Detection

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, object-detection, testing, precision

I am training some Object-Detection-Models from the TensorFlow Object Detection API and got from the evaluation with MS COCO metrics the following results for Average Precision:

IoU = 0.5;0.9
maxDets = 100
area = small
AP = -1.000

The other values all make sense to me. But I don´t know what the -1.000 stands for. Does it mean that there are no small objects in my dataset to be detected?

Answer (score 0):

**APsmall** stands for **Average Precision for small objects**.

---

This website contains all the descriptions about the metrics:
https://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval

If you want to know more about the metrics evaluation (how to calculate this metric), you can find the metric's source code here: https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocotools/cocoeval.py

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that there are no small objects in my dataset to be detected?

Yes.

From the evaluation source code as mentioned by the other answer, [L334](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/8c9bcc3cf640524c4c20a9c40e89cb6a2f2fa0e9/PythonAPI/pycocotools/cocoeval.py#L334):

> -1 for the precision of absent categories

From the coco dataset website, [Detection Evaluation](https://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval):

> $AP_{small}$: AP for small objects: area < $32^{2}$
> $AP_{medium}$: AP for medium objects: $32^{2}$ < area < $96^{2}$
> $AP_{large}$: AP for large objects: area > $96^{2}$